# Question about multi-tiered XML generated from a SQL statement / procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm tinkering with how to take a SQL statement (well from within a stored procedure) and generate an XML output from the results of the query. The output I'm after in XML looks like this:

```
<Application>
    <Device AppEnabled="true" AsOf="06/03/2019 16:01:58 UTC" Name="MachineName">
        <Groups>
            <Group Name="Administrators" ReportChanges="true">
                <Members>
                    <Member Name="AdminUser1" />
                    <Member Name="AdminUser2" />
                    <Member Name="AdminUser3" />
                    <Member Name="AdminUser4" />
                </Members>
            </Group>
            <Group Name="Normal Users" ReportChanges="true">
                <Members>
                    <Member Name="NormalUser1" />
                    <Member Name="NormalUser2" />
                </Members>
            </Group>
        </Groups>
    </Device>
</Application>
```

The 'AdminUser1' and 'NormalUser1' all come from two separate queries. For the sake of simplicity we'll say the queries look as follows:

```
SELECT UserName 
FROM AdminUsers 
WHERE Computer = 'ComputerName'

SELECT UserName 
FROM NormalUsers 
WHERE Computer = 'ComputerName'
```

Ideally we'd take in the 'ComputerName' as a parameter. The 'AsOf' would be the current time stamp. The 'AppEnabled' would come from another query that checks to see if this computer is setup to use the application more or less. I'm thinking that I could just look that up and store the value in a variable.

The other item is that the 'reportchanges=true' actually comes from yet another query that looks for any items to add in to the 'Group Name=xxx' item. So there is a table that holds settings and values that I'd include in that header. Currently there is only one additional item (that being ReportChanges=true) but there could be multiple items. That query would look something like this:

```
SELECT XMLSetting, XMLValue 
FROM XMLItems;
```

I've been tinkering with the 'FOR XML' on a query which can get the Members / Member group formatted right, but how would I add in all the other layers?

Comment: You'd need to use nested queries (sub queries), without sample data though, this is difficult to an example that may help you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format will need quite a lot of nested levels. Try it like this (and the next time please provide sample data in consumable format like I do it here with DDL and INSERT):

```
DECLARE @AdminUsers TABLE(UserName VARCHAR(100),Computer VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @NormalUsers TABLE(UserName VARCHAR(100),Computer VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @AdminUsers VALUES('Admin1','blah')
                             ,('Admin2','blah')
                             ,('Admin3','Other');
INSERT INTO @NormalUsers VALUES('user1','blah')
                              ,('user2','blah')
                              ,('user3','Other');

DECLARE @ComputerName VARCHAR(100)='blah';

SELECT 'true' AS [Device/@AppEnabled]
      ,GETDATE() AS [Device/@AsOf]
      ,@ComputerName AS [Device/@MachineName]
      ,(
        SELECT
           (
                SELECT 'Administrators' AS [@Name]
                      ,'true' AS [@ReportChanges]
                      ,(
                        SELECT UserName AS [Member/@name]
                        FROM @AdminUsers 
                        WHERE Computer=@ComputerName 
                        FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Members'),TYPE
                       ) AS [*]
                FOR XML PATH('Group'),TYPE
            ) AS [*]
          ,(
                SELECT 'Normal Users' AS [@Name]
                      ,'true' AS [@ReportChanges]
                      ,(
                        SELECT UserName AS [Member/@name]
                        FROM @NormalUsers 
                        WHERE Computer=@ComputerName 
                        FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Members'),TYPE
                       ) AS [*]
                FOR XML PATH('Group'),TYPE
            ) AS [*]
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ) AS [Device/Groups]
FOR XML PATH('Application'),TYPE;
```

The result

```
<Application>
  <Device AppEnabled="true" AsOf="2019-06-04T10:10:50.160" MachineName="blah">
    <Groups>
      <Group Name="Administrators" ReportChanges="true">
        <Members>
          <Member name="Admin1" />
          <Member name="Admin2" />
        </Members>
      </Group>
      <Group Name="Normal Users" ReportChanges="true">
        <Members>
          <Member name="user1" />
          <Member name="user2" />
        </Members>
      </Group>
    </Groups>
  </Device>
</Application>
```

### UPDATE

Another approach with the same result

```
WITH Groups AS
(
    SELECT 'Administrators' AS GroupName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Normal Users'
)
SELECT 'true' AS [@AppEnabled]
      ,GETDATE() AS [@AsOf]
      ,@ComputerName AS [@MachineName]
      ,(
        SELECT GroupName AS [@name]
              ,'true' AS [@ReportChanges]
              ,(
                SELECT names.*
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT UserName AS [@Name] FROM @AdminUsers WHERE GroupName='Administrators' AND Computer=@ComputerName 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT UserName AS [@Name] FROM @NormalUsers WHERE GroupName='Normal Users' AND Computer=@ComputerName
                ) names
                FOR XML PATH('Member'),TYPE
               ) AS Members
        FROM Groups
        FOR XML PATH('Group'),TYPE
       ) AS Groups
FOR XML PATH('Device'),ROOT('Application');
```

Comment: awesome - thanks for the info - I will certainly give that a try!